# Uninstall Older Sql Server After Upgrade

Tags: sql-server, installation, uninstall, upgrade

Is it ok to uninstall older versions of SQL Server after an upgrade?  I have 2008/2008 R2 installed, but using 2014 since it was just upgraded.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After successful upgrade an old installation of SQL Server just useless. 
Feel free to remove it if no any other not upgraded services (Integration Services, Analysis Services, Reporting services, etc) exists.